# Comparing variables in script

Tags: shell-script

I have this statement `if [ ! - f "$i" -o "$i"x = "$MTR"x]` and was wondering what does this statement achieves. I understand that the first part check if the variable `i` is not a file, but cannot figure out what is the second part after the `-o` (which stand for logical OR I think). Any help will be most helpful.

Comment: are you sure there is a space between `-` and `f`. I think it should be `-f` without a space.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the -o stands for a logical OR.
The `"$i"x = "$MTR"x` compares the content of the to variables `$i` and `$MTR`.
I think the `x` is added to both variables to avoid problems if any of the two variables is not set or not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the statement is

```
if [ ! -f "$i" -o "$i"x = "$MTR"x ]
```

The `-f "$i"` checks whether the value `$i` corresponds to a regular file (or a symbolic link to a regular file). This test is then negated with `!`.  The `-o` is an antiquated and obsolete way of saying "logical OR".

The `"$i"x = "$MTR"x` tests, in an somewhat awkward way that may have been neccessary in really old implementations of the `sh` shell, whether `$i` and `$MTR` is the same string.

In a (current) standard `sh` shell, the statement would be written

```
if [ ! -f "$i" ] || [ "$i" = "$MTR" ]
```

or, with a bit of logic applied,

```
if [ "$i" = "$MTR" ] && [ -f "$i" ] || [ ! -f "$i" ]
```

In words: The statement is true if `$i` is same string as `$MTR` and they refer to an existing regular file (or a symbolic link to one),  or if `$i` is not the name of a file.

It may be more interesting to look at what it means for this statement to be *false*.  It's only ever false if `$i` and `$MTR` is not the same string *and* `$i` refers to an existing file.